# Замена хеша пароля пользователя в домене

Tags: windows, администрирование, хеширование, active-directory, контроллер-домена

Описание: Есть домен AD "test.rdi" с контроллером домена на windows server 2016,  на котором лежит ntds.dit, в котором хранится хеш пароля пользователя домена "p_morozov@test.rdi".
Права и пароль админа на сервере есть, пароль админа домена тоже есть.

Вопрос №1 : в случае замены хеша пароля пользователя домена "p_morozov@test.rdi" на другой заранее сгенерированный (по известному новому паролю) хеш в файле ntds.dit, можно ли будет залогинится с новым паролем пользователю "p_morozov@test.rdi" или нужно произвести еще какието манипуляции?

Вопрос №2 : чем можно отредактировать ntds.dit?

Comment: Теоретически наверное да, но я бы делал штатными средствами смену пароля.

Comment: Практически оказалось что подменить хеш пароля пользователя AD и тем самым изменить пароль можно, но делается это через powershell модуль DSInternals , командой Set-ADAccountPasswordHash

Comment: Ну это вполне можно назвать штатной функцией, потому что всё-таки пошик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже я сам нашел ответ на свой вопрос.

1. Да в случае замены значения поля NThash учетной записи пользователя на другой с генерированный NThash (по уже известному слову) в файле ntds.dit, пароль пользователя Active Directory будет заменен позволяет пройти авторизацию.
2. Редактировать ntds.dit довольно затруднительно , поэтому для замены хеша пароля лучше использовать штатные средства powershell, а именно модуль DSInternals и команду "Set-ADAccountPasswordHash" пример использования:

   ```
   Set-ADAccountPasswordHash -SamAccountName p_morozov -Domain test -Server test  -NTHash 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx’
   ```